# HTML5 audio blob would not play on Android

Tags: android, html, google-app-engine, html5-audio, blobstore

I'm serving an audio file (WAV file that contains a short uncompressed PCM) from my GAE app using BlobStore.
On a click event, I set `audio.src` and call `audio.play()`.

Now here is the weird part:

- When working locally - it plays well on both IOS and Android.
- After deploying to GAE, it plays well on IOS - **but not on Android**!

No error is shown - it just plays nothing.
As far as I can tell from GAE logs, the audio file *is* served in all cases.
In case of Android I can see a requests from "Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android 4.4.2 (stagefright alternative)".

Any idea what's going on, or how to debug this?

---

### Update

Tried playing files from Google Cloud Storage, according to Stuart Langley's suggestion.
In that case, **Android plays well, and IOS doesn't** (intermittently. Sometimes gives an error).

So a workaround that works for me is storing the file on Cloud Storage, and also calling `createGsBlobKey` in order to serve it as a blob.
On the client side I check whether it's Android (`navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)`). In case of Android I set `audio.src` to the Cloud Storage file, and in case of IOS I set it to my servlet which serves the file using `BlobstoreService.serve` with the blob key I got from `createGsBlobKey`.

This is a cumbersome workaround and I didn't check other mobile OSs to see what works for each, so if anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is due to the chunked response when serving a blob.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3219) is an issue tracker item about audio files not playing correctly in some browsers.

[Here](http://audio-test.appspot.com/) is a test web site I put together while back that illustrates the problem.

As for workarounds - You can put the file on cloud storage and then play it from there, as long as you're not concerned about people hotlinking the file.

Comment: I'll check that out. However, Google Cloud Storage requires billing which I didn't enable...

Comment: No it doesn't - every app has free quota on cloud storage.

Comment: So [google pricing page](https://developers.google.com/storage/pricing) is probably out of date (_"Important: Google Cloud Storage requires billing information for all accounts before you can start using the service..."_). I'll give it a try.

Comment: Tried your test web site now, and chuncked response *seems to work fine* on Android. I'm still puzzled...

Comment: Tried your suggestion (Thanks!), see question update.